# Axis title overlaps axis ticks using rmarkdown + plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Axis title overlaps axis ticks when use plotly inside rmarkdown. i've tried [Plot margins in RMarkdown/knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827651/plot-margins-in-rmarkdown-knitr), [R: ggplot and plotly axis margin won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763280/r-ggplot-and-plotly-axis-margin-wont-change) and [Y Axis - Margin Size](https://community.plot.ly/t/y-axis-margin-size/4404).  No success.  Show you my code:

only ggplot works fine:

````
    ---
    title: |
      SLIDES
   author: |
      ME   
   date: |
      `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`

   output: slidy_presentation
   runtime: knitr
   ---
```{r my.chunk, echo=FALSE, fig.width = 18, fig.height = 9, results='asis', message=FALSE}
   require(ggplot2)
   require(plotly)
   d<-data.frame(Year=rep(c(2020:2024),6),Group=rep(c('A','B','C'),each=10),Item=rep(c('w','v'),each=5),
                 Value=round(runif(30,100,500),0))
   g<-ggplot(d, aes(Year,Value,fill=Item ))+ 
     geom_bar( position = "stack", stat = "summary", fun.y = "sum",na.rm=T)+
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
     scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','green'), breaks=c('w','v'))+ labs(title='TITLE',x = 'Year', y = 'Value')+
     facet_grid(. ~ Group)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,size=11,margin = margin(b = 5)))

   print(g)
```
````

[image: Plot with ggplot only]

If use plotly x axis title overlaps axis ticks labels:

````
    ---
    title: |
      SLIDES
   author: |
      ME   
   date: |
      `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`

   output: slidy_presentation
   runtime: knitr
   ---
```{r my.chunk, echo=FALSE, fig.width = 18, fig.height = 9, results='asis', message=FALSE}
   require(ggplot2)
   require(plotly)
   d<-data.frame(Year=rep(c(2020:2024),6),Group=rep(c('A','B','C'),each=10),Item=rep(c('w','v'),each=5),
                 Value=round(runif(30,100,500),0))
   g<-ggplot(d, aes(Year,Value,fill=Item ))+ 
     geom_bar( position = "stack", stat = "summary", fun.y = "sum",na.rm=T)+
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
     scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','green'), breaks=c('w','v'))+ labs(title='TITLE',x = 'Year', y = 'Value')+
     facet_grid(. ~ Group)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,size=11,margin = margin(b = 5)))

    ggplotly(g)%>%
    config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>%
    layout(hovermode = 'compare')
````

[image]    ```

thanks

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1224)

Comment: add margin arguments to layout settings not works 
 
        ggplotly(g)%>%
        config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>%
        layout(hovermode = 'compare',xaxis = list(automargin=TRUE),yaxis = 
        list(automargin=TRUE))

Answer (score 2):

Finally i've solved using

```
   g[['x']][['layout']][["annotations"]][[1]]$y<- -0.15
```

with g as plotly object

Regards

Comment: Where did you find this, I have been trying to solve this for so long. Can you explain it a little?

Comment: Excuses for taking so long to respond, but I was offline for a long period. I solved the issue from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763280/r-ggplot-and-plotly-axis-margin-wont-change

What I can understand is that it is about modifying properties of the plotly object, in this case, Y position of the label that contains the title on the X axis.